# edit path with unknown segment using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a path in a file that I need to edit, something like the following. Anything after "newest" and before "/" will need to be included in the match.

```
/home/test/files/newestaaabbb/the_file.txt
/home/test/files/newest1/the_file.txt
/home/test/files/newest4_8/the_file.txt
```

would all need to become:

```
/home/test/files/oldest/the_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` with this regex `newest[^/]` as search pattern:

```
sed 's~newest[^/]*~oldest~' file
/home/test/files/oldest/the_file.txt
/home/test/files/oldest/the_file.txt
/home/test/files/oldest/the_file.txt
```

**PS:** For *inline editing* of the file use:

```
sed -i.bak 's~newest[^/]*~oldest~' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way if to pipe through awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";OFS="/"}; {if ($(NF-1) ~ "^newest") $(NF-1)="oldest";print}'
```